# SSIS sysssislog table - Is Starttime or EndTime logged as UTC?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, ssis-2017

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/sysssislog-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) doesn't say much other than

> starttime datetime    The time the package began to run.

Does this log as UTC ?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using msdb to execute the packages, and not SSISDB?

Comment: sorry, was that comment directed at me @Larnu? I am using SSISDB

Comment: Yes it was. If you're using SSISDB then your logs won't be in the table `msdb.dbo.sysssislog`; they're be stored in SSISDB, and are accessed via the Integration Service Catalogs node in the Object Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using SSISDB, not msdb. The table you reference (msdb.dbo.sysssislog`) is used by one of the (old) package deployment methods for SSIS, not the new project deployment method of SSISDB.

The logs stored by SSISDB are access by browsing to the package in the Integration Services Catalogs node in the Object Explorer of SSMS; navigate to the project and package, right click it and select Reports and then the one you want.

All the times displayed in the SSISDB logs are accurate to the second, and are displayed in the server's local time.